# Problems with pointers and memory adresses

Tags: c++

I wonder why this code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int *pointer = (int*)0x02F70BCC;
cout<<*pointer;
return 0;
}
```

In my opinion it should write on the screen value of 0x02F70BCC,
instead of this my programm crashes.
I know that memory with adress 0x02F70BCC stores value of 20.
But like I said no matter what it just doesn't want to show correct number.
Please help me guys, detailed explanation would be very nice of you.

Comment: Do not dereference the pointer for printing it's value: `cout<<pointer;`

Comment: What exactly do you expect to see printed on the screen?

Comment: Value of "0x02F70BC" Memory adress which is 20. So basicly I want a 20 on the screen.

Comment: @Seoner: The word you are looking for is *"at"*, not *"of"*.

Comment: How do you know that the value is 20? You can't access memory of other processes in case you try that.

Comment: @user0815 it's 20 in specific situation. To be more detailed I want to learn more about pointers, memory and so on... so I opened up Heroes 3 created new game then in "Cheat engine" found correct memory adress (or it is pointer, isn't it?) which always show amount of wood resources in game. So I've got memory adress that cointains information about wood in the game and I want my program to show it in cmd window. –

Comment: It's not that easy. You should have a look at [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read the memory of another process.

Comment: @Seoner: Cheat Engine gave you a memory address that is relative to the Heroes3 process, not your app's process.  To read/write values in another process, you need to open the process using [`OpenProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) first.  This validates whether your app even has permission to access the process. If successful, you can then use [`ReadProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx)/[`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx) as needed.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your effort !!

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Just saw it, wow, that's really nice what you did there, I appreciate that a lot !!! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you won't get access to **every** location in memory you want. Not every location in memory is valid, you may want to read about [Virtual Address Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space).

Some addresses are reserved for device drivers and kernel mode operations. Another range of addresses (for example `0xCCCCCCCC` and higher) may be reserved for uninitialized pointers.

Even if some location is valid, operating system may still deny access to write to/read from certain location, if that would cause undefined behaviour or violate system safety.

**EDIT**

I think you might be interested in creating some kind of "GameHack", that allows you to modify amount of resources, number of units, experience level, attributes or anything.

Memory access is not a simple topic. Different OSes use different strategies to prevent security violations. But many thing can be done here, after all there is a lot software for doing such things.

First of all, do you really need to write your own tool? If you just want some cheating, use [ArtMoney](http://www.artmoney.ru/) - it is a great memory editor, that I have been using for years.

But if you **really have to** write it manually, you need to do some research first.
On Windows, for example, I would start from these:

[ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also, I am quite certain, that one of possible techniques is to pretend, that you are a debugger:

[DebugActiveProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679295%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT 2**

I have done some research and it looks, that on Windows (I assume this is your platform, since you mentioned gaming; can't imagine playing anything on crappy Linux), steps required to write another process' memory are:

**1.** Enumerate processes: ([EnumProcesses](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
const size_t MAX_PROC_NUM = 512;

DWORD procIDs[MAX_PROC_NUM] = { 0 };
DWORD idsNum = 0;

if(!EnumProcesses(procIDs, sizeof(DWORD) * MAX_PROC_NUM, &idsNum))
  //handle error here

idsNum /= sizeof(DWORD); //After EnumProcesses(), idsNum contains number of BYTES!
```

**2.** Open required process. ([OpenProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx),[GetModuleFileNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
const char* game_exe_path = "E:\\Games\\Spellforce\\Spellforce.exe"; //Example

HANDLE game_proc_handle = nullptr;
DWORD proc_access = PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_VM_WRITE; //read & write memory, query info needed to get .exe name

const DWORD MAX_EXE_PATH_LEN = 1024;

for(DWORD n = 0 ; n < idsNum ; ++idsNum)
{
  DWORD current_id = procIDs[n];
  HANDLE current_handle = OpenProcess(proc_access, false, current_id);

  if(!current_handle)
  {
    //handle error here
    continue;
  }

  char current_path[MAX_EXE_PATH_LEN];

  DWORD length = GetModuleFileNameEx(current_handle, nullptr, current_path, MAX_EXE_PATH_LEN);

  if(length > 0)
  {
    if(strcmp(current_path, game_exe_path) == 0) //that's our game!
    {
      game_proc_handle = current_handle;
      break;
    }
  }

  CloseHandle(current_handle); //don't forget this!
}

if(!game_proc_handle)
  //sorry, game not found
```

**3.** Write memory ([WriteProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
void* pointer = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0x02F70BCC);
int new_value = 5000; //value to be written

BOOL success = WriteProcessMemory(game_proc_handle, pointer, &new_value, sizeof(int), nullptr);

if(success)
  //data successfully written!
else
  //well, that's... em...
```

This code is written just 'as is', but I see no errors, so you can use it as your starting point. I also provided links for all functions I used, so with some additional research (if necessary), you can achieve what you are trying to.

Cheers.

Comment: Well I want to do it myself just to learn something ;P Thank you a lot for your effort tho. ! : )

Answer (score -1):

When you use,

```
cout<<*pointer;
```

the program tries to dereference the value of the pointer and writes the value at the address.

If you want to print just the pointer, use:

```
cout << pointer;
```

Example:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 20;
    int* p = &i;

    std::cout << *p << std::endl;  // print the value stored at the address
                                   // pointed to by p. In this case, it will
                                   // print the value of i, which is 20

    std::cout << p << std::endl;   // print the address that p points to
                                   // It will print the address of i.
}
```

Comment: When I use just cout<<pointer; it shows me "0x02F70BCC" while I want to have the value of "0x02F70BCC".

Comment: @Seoner And what on earth is "the value of "0x02F70BCC""?

Comment: @juanchopanza it's 20 in specific situation. To be more detailed I want to learn more about pointers, memory and so on... so I opened up Heroes 3 created new game then in "Cheat engine" found correct memory adress (or it is pointer, isn't it?) which always show amount of wood resources in game. So I've got memory adress that cointains information about wood in the game and I want my program to show it in cmd window.